# Can I set the build number in VSTS build

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-artifacts

When I create a new build definition then build number starts with 1. It gets increment with each build.

Can I set the initial build number instead it takes the default value (1)?

In the existing build definition can I bump the number, assume current build number is 1345, I want to add a offset of 1000 so that build number would be 2345?

Comment: Do you mean build id or the build number rev?

Comment: I mean build number. Currently I use Build.BuildNumber parameter variable with MSBuild task. For new or cloned build number it starts with x.y.1.0 where x is the major number & y is the minor number, 1 is the build number. I want to start the build number to say 400 instead of 1. Is it possible to define some kind of offset?

Comment: Can you share the settings for your Build Number Format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can determine the build number format in the Options tab:
[image]

Comment: This is setting the format, not that value in itself. How is this marked as the best answer?!

Answer (score 2):

Point of clarification: What you're talking about is the **build ID**, not the **build number**.

You can control the build **number** format as described in Shayki's answer.

However, the build **id** is a system-controlled unique identifier that you cannot change.